How to modify my custom domain to default domain in Azure portal
Somehow, a custom domain of my old company is assigned to my default directory. Now all I want is to restore it to my default domain as per my user id. So if the id is my_id@outlook.com then I think my domain will be my_id.onmicrosoft.com. I tried to delete the existing company custom domain but not permitted. If I try to create new domain my_id.onmicrosoft.com I get an error. Any solution? thanks.



Those who code Azure infra in terraform knows the in and outs of infra but that is fine to remove it.

The .onmicrosoft.com domain is a default domain on tenants. It's not modifiable or removable. I don't see how your tenant's domain has changed to this..

Are you the owner of the subscription or tenant. @drmaa

Adding to the point given by @juunas, on.microsoft.com is the default domain in Azure tenants and it cannot be modified easily. Instead, you can create a new custom domain use it, add the users in newly created domain without impacting others.

The other workaround is:
Once the domain has been created, you can make that as "primary domain" and use it.

Refer MSDoc for achieving the above requirement.
Note: You need to have Global Administrator role to create multiple domains under a tenant.
I have created a new custom domain as shown below:

There is another approach using  PowerShell to make a custom domain a default and it is also possible in only few scenarios.
Use Set-MsolDomain command to make a custom domain to default.
Set-MsolDomain -Name "newdomain.com" -IsDefault
Or directly visit office 365 admin portal and modify it accordingly.
Also try reaching out support team and raise a request on the same issue.
